# Undefined reference to 'setup' and 'loop' using CMake for custom project

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement a CLI uploader for an Arduino MEGA2560 using rosserial_arduino and CMake, based upon http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/CMake under LUbuntu 14.04 with ROS-Indigo on an ODROID (ARM) development board.

The tutorial works fine, as can be seen here:

```
$ catkin_make helloworld_firmware_hello-upload
Base path: /home/odroid/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/odroid/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make helloworld_firmware_hello-upload -j8 -l8" in "/home/odroid/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestServiceInfo
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Log
Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TopicInfo
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestMessageInfo
Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestParam
[ 87%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 87%] Built target rosserial_msgs_genpy
[100%] Built target helloworld_ros_lib
-- Generating hello
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/build/helloworld/firmware
[100%] Built target helloworld_firmware
make[4]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
[ 90%] Built target mega2560_CORE
[100%] Built target hello

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9801
avrdude: reading input file "/home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/share/helloworld/hello.hex"
avrdude: input file /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/share/helloworld/hello.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (9854 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 1.60s

avrdude: 9854 bytes of flash written
avrdude: reading input file "/home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/share/helloworld/hello.eep"
avrdude: writing eeprom (0 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: 0 bytes of eeprom written

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:E6, E:D8, L:E6)

avrdude done.  Thank you.

[100%] Built target hello-upload
[100%] Built target helloworld_firmware_hello-upload
```

However, when I create a new catkin_package for my desired file (which is actually a symbolic link to a ../sketchbook/ Arduino project due to the need for both IDE and non-IDE uploading (some students are competent with CLI, others GUI)), I get the following output (I have removed the Policy CMP0022 warnings from this output):

```
$ catkin_make mechbot_v3_firmware_code-upload
Base path: /home/odroid/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/odroid/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make mechbot_v3_firmware_code-upload -j8 -l8" in "/home/odroid/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TopicInfo
Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Log
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestServiceInfo
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestParam
Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestMessageInfo
[ 87%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 87%] Built target rosserial_msgs_genpy
[100%] Built target mechbot_v3_ros_lib
-- Generating code
-- Configuring done
... lots of Policy CMP0022 warnings removed ...
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/odroid/catkin_ws/build/mechbot_v3/firmware
[100%] Built target mechbot_v3_firmware
Scanning dependencies of target mechbot_v3_firmware_code-upload
make[4]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
[ 71%] Built target mega2560_CORE
[ 78%] Built target mega2560_Wire
[ 82%] Built target mega2560_ITG3200
[ 85%] Built target mega2560_HMC58X3
[ 89%] Built target mega2560_Servo
[ 92%] Built target mega2560_ADXL345
[ 96%] Built target mega2560_LiquidCrystal
[ 96%] Built target mega2560_PinChangeInt
Linking CXX executable /home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/share/mechbot_v3/code.elf
libmega2560_CORE.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `setup'
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `loop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[7]: *** [/home/odroid/catkin_ws/devel/share/mechbot_v3/code.elf] Error 1
make[6]: *** [CMakeFiles/code.dir/all] Error 2
make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/code-upload.dir/rule] Error 2
make[4]: *** [code-upload] Error 2
make[3]: *** [mechbot_v3/CMakeFiles/mechbot_v3_firmware_code-upload] Error 2
make[2]: *** [mechbot_v3/CMakeFiles/mechbot_v3_firmware_code-upload.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [mechbot_v3/CMakeFiles/mechbot_v3_firmware_code-upload.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [mechbot_v3_firmware_code-upload] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

The file in question compiles and uploads fine through the Arduino IDE, and the two functions are definitely in the .ino file (which is substantially too big to post here):

```
void setup() {}
void loop() {}
```

For reference, the CMakeLists.txt file within the project is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mechbot_v3)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rosserial_arduino rosserial_client)

catkin_package()

rosserial_generate_ros_lib(PACKAGE rosserial_arduino SCRIPT make_libraries.py)

rosserial_configure_client(DIRECTORY firmware TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${ROSSERIAL_ARDUINO_TOOLCHAIN})

rosserial_add_client_target(firmware code ALL)
rosserial_add_client_target(firmware code-upload)
```

The CMakeLists.txt file within the ./firmware/ sub-directory is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

include_directories(${ROS_LIB_DIR})

generate_arduino_firmware(code SRCS mechbot_v3.ino ${ROS_LIB_DIR}/time.cpp BOARD mega2560 PORT /dev/ttyACM0)
#generate_arduino_firmware(code SRCS mechbot_v3.ino BOARD mega2560 PORT /dev/ttyACM0)
```

And the library definitions within the .ino file are:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include "std_msgs/Int32MultiArray.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.h"
#include "std_msgs/UInt8MultiArray.h"
#include "std_msgs/UInt8.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32.h"
#include "std_msgs/Int32.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <PinChangeInt.h>
#include <ADXL345.h>
#include <HMC58X3.h>
#include <ITG3200.h>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem may be? First time delving into the non-IDE environment.

*EDIT 1*: Corrected error in project CMakeLists.txt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199696/undefined-reference-to-%27setup%27-and-%27loop%27-using-cmake-for-custom-project/) by [anonymousSnowMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3930/anonymoussnowman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested [on the issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/154#issuecomment-67488970), please try using the `generate_arduino_firmware(SKETCH xyz)` syntax of `arduino-cmake`.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymousSnowMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3930/anonymoussnowman/) on 2014-12-18**:
This corrected the issue. Entry required was:

generate_arduino_firmware(program SKETCH file.ino SRCS ${ROS_LIB_DIR}/time.cpp BOARD mega2560 PORT /dev/ttyACM0)

Why is there a SRCS and a SKETCH entry if they behave the same, as I have shown by simply renaming one to the other?